Bad guy taking a drug
I keep remembering a scene from a film where a guy takes a pill, but I'm unable to recall anything else about the film and it's bugging me.
The guy takes a pill by popping it into his mouth, leaning his head back and cracking it between his molars. He then gives a facial expression and twitch as the drug quickly kicks in. The scene is shot from an above perspective so you can see his facial expression as he leans back. It's a defining trait of the character and he does this a few times in the film.
I can't remember if this was a cops/bad guys or sci-fi film. It's an actor known to play bad guys and it was likely a popular film. I want to say it was an Arnold film but I'm not sure. I think it was an action hero/bad guy film.
It must have come out in the last 10 or 15 years???

As a wild guess: wasn't it Gary Oldman in Leon ( pic , video clip)?

Are you saying "bill" but meaning "pill"?

@Paulster2 lol, thanks I think I need to take a few bills of my own.

You and me both ...

Famous scene from Léon matches your description. 
Gary Oldman as Norman Stansfield - corrupt police officer, drug addict and main antagonist of the movie - takes the drug leaning backwards and his face is shown from above.

Video clip on Youtube

thanks! that was it. I couldn't get that scene out of my head. lol
